# Smoothly moving an object sideways by a certain amount when a key is pressed Unity C#

Tags: unity, c#, vector, lerp

I basically want to have the user press A once without holding it down, to **smoothly** move the player to the left. I would like to make the player move to the left by -12. So he would end up going from 0 to -12 or from -12 to -24.

Comment: You can do this pretty neatly with coroutines, but the details will hinge on how exactly you want it to play out. How long should a single slide take? If the player presses the button again during the slide, should it have no effect, or make the slide longer, or queue-up a second slide? Should the slide be constant velocity or have some easing in & out? Should the player character respond to collisions during the slide? Stuff like that. (Gamedev is complicated) ;)

Comment: I already have different methods, but they just don't work as well. Could you give me a tutorial or guide on how to use this? (Script reference or anything else is fine)

Comment: As I said, the details vary depending on how you want this to work. Edit the question to fill in the blanks I called out above and we can probably get you sorted out.

Comment: It should play out for 1.5 seconds (I can always change it later); if the player presses the button again during the slide, it will queue up the second slide; It should slowly start the movement and then slow down at the end; collisions still work during that time.

Comment: Hey, I'm not sure if you are still going to respond any time soon, but I am going to try to do some of it myself.

Comment: K, I found out most of the things myself. If you could respond, that would be great as I have some small questions.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! Feel free to post your solution as an answer if you have what you need. This isn't a chat room for live back-and-forth, but we do have [chat] for that purpose.  I'll be offline for a bit, but I'll try to check here in the morning to see if you've edited your question to detail any remaining issues.

Comment: I'm fine for now. I actually have everything I need, but I just wanna get rid of all of the flaws, so I will go to the chat for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is you have to Lerp between 2 values from the current position. And you have to StartCoroutine only when Input.GetKeyDown() - the keyword is Down, so it will start only when you press, but not hold or release it, so it will start only 1 coroutine, it's important when you move something with coroutines you don't want the object to be moved by 2 different forces that don't depend one on another unless it's planned.

Here is the code to do it.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveObjectWithCoroutines : MonoBehaviour {

public float movementSpeed = 5f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        MoveObjectTo(this.transform, new Vector3(this.transform.position.x - 12, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z), movementSpeed);
        /*
         * If you want to move it every time by -12 (new Vector3(this.transform.position.x -12, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z)), 
         * or by some other value and axis - just change 
         * the targetPosition Vector3 passed in the argument of MoveObjectTo(); 
         */
    }

}

private void MoveObjectTo(Transform objectToMove, Vector3 targetPosition, float moveSpeed)
{
    StopCoroutine(MoveObject(objectToMove, targetPosition, moveSpeed));
    StartCoroutine(MoveObject(objectToMove, targetPosition, moveSpeed));
}

public static IEnumerator MoveObject(Transform objectToMove, Vector3 targetPosition, float moveSpeed)
{
    float currentProgress = 0;
    Vector3 cashedObjectPosition = objectToMove.transform.position;

    while (currentProgress <= 1)
    {
        currentProgress += moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        objectToMove.position = Vector3.Lerp(cashedObjectPosition, targetPosition, currentProgress);

        yield return null;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: The first paragraph looks like it would make a better comment for the other answer, but the rest is pretty good. +1